# Cypress url regex does not match

Tags: regex, cypress

I am trying to check for current location in cypress. I want to check the url should have string `register/` followed by `numbers` of any digit.

I am doing `cy.url().should('match', new RegExp('.+?register\/\d+'))`

**URL** = `http://localhost:8888/wachigroup/#!/register/82` 
**Regex** = `new RegExp('.+?register\/\d+')`

I also tried the regex here https://regex101.com/r/1HxZq3/1/ which seems work fine.

BUT It is failing in cypress as the error below. Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: So, why do you use a constructor? Use `Regex = /.+?register\/\d+/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, double escaped worked. Reason i tried constructor because it complains `CypressError: 'match' requires its argument be a 'RegExp'. You passed: '/.+?register/d+/'`

Comment: Well, `'/.+?register/d+/'` is not a regex. `/.+?register/d+/` is.